# Load multiple youtube videos from a single modal in Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have over 50 youtube videos to show in a modal on a static page. Of course, each modal has a separate button. However, I don't want to create 50 different modal. So here's what I got so far

**DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/b4a1ekyw/**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
         <h2>Modal Example</h2>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg modalButton" data-name="Clicked Modal 1" data-toggle="modal">Open Modal 1</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg modalButton" data-name="Clicked Modal 2" data-toggle="modal">Open Modal 2</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg modalButton" data-name="Clicked Modal 3" data-toggle="modal">Open Modal 3</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg modalButton" data-name="Clicked Modal 4" data-toggle="modal">Open Modal 4</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg modalButton" data-name="Clicked Modal 5" data-toggle="modal">Open Modal 5</button>
         <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
               <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">

                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#myModal').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false,
        show: false,
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".modalButton", function() {
        var ClickedButton = $(this).data("name");
        $(".modal-body").html("<p>" + ClickedButton + "</p>");
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });

});
```

This is an example code to show the youtube video:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

I don't know how to call this video code in `data-name`.

Comment: Is this what you want https://jsfiddle.net/jr1cbL3y/

Comment: YES!! Please post it as an answer.

Comment: What you could do is have an AJAX Function that parses the video url to your modal and then each modal carries a different url, so dependant on which button was clicked, a different video shows up. That way you only ever have to worry about having one modal coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is modyfi you code a bit, so insted of:

```
$(".modal-body").html("<p>" + ClickedButton + "</p>");
```

use this:

```
$(".modal-body").html('<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + ClickedButton + '" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>');
```

**Full code**

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#myModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false,
    show: false,
  });
  $(document).on("click", ".modalButton", function() {
    var ClickedButton = $(this).data("name");
    $(".modal-body").html('<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + ClickedButton + '" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>');
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });

});
```

```css
h2,
h4,
.btn,
.modal-body {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg modalButton" data-name="zpOULjyy-n8" data-toggle="modal">Open Modal 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg modalButton" data-name="Clicked Modal 2" data-toggle="modal">Open Modal 2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg modalButton" data-name="Clicked Modal 3" data-toggle="modal">Open Modal 3</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg modalButton" data-name="Clicked Modal 4" data-toggle="modal">Open Modal 4</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg modalButton" data-name="Clicked Modal 5" data-toggle="modal">Open Modal 5</button>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```